# Is there a notation for the unique value that satisfies a predicate?

Tags: logic, soft-question, notation, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Let's say that we have a predicate $\phi$ such that $\exists!x.\phi(x)$. Is there a notation for denoting the unique value of $\phi$?

Of course you can just say "let $x$ be the unique value such that $\phi(x)$", but that's a phrase, not a notation.

There's a "hacky" ways to accomplish this

$$\bigcup_{x \in \{x | \phi(x)\}}x \text { (you can also do this with $\bigcap, \sum, \prod, \inf, \sup, \min, \max$, expected value, etc...)}$$

but that obviously is rather confusing. You can do it nicely with Hilbert's epsilon ($\epsilon x. \phi(x)$), but it does not require that $\phi$ has a unique value satisfying it. It doesn't even require $\phi$ to satisfied by *any* value.

I suppose something like $\epsilon !x.\phi(x)$ would work, but I have never seen anybody use that notation before.

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question, but I have sometimes seen $\textrm{argmin}\{f(x),x \in A\}$ for a value where the minimum value of the function $f$ is reached. You may adapt this notation. Nice question by the way.

Comment: $\textrm{argtrue}$, I guess? If I were inventing a new notation, I would use the $\epsilon !$, but getting new notation accepted is hard.

Comment: Interpreting a predicate $\phi$ on a set $X$ as a function $X \to \{ \mathrm{true}, \mathrm{false} \}$ you could write $\phi^{-1}(\mathrm{true}).$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Following the example of [*Principia Mathematica*](https://books.google.it/books?id=ke9yGmFy24sC&pg=PA30), it is customary [*sic* !] to use a [definite description operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_description#Mathematical_logic) symbolized using the "turned" (rotated) Greek lower case iota character "$\iota$" [it must be "\turnediota"].

The notation $\iota x (\phi x)$ means

> "$\text { the unique } x \text { such that } \phi x$".

Comment: That is the correct answer, but it would be kind to advise the OP not to use that notation. There doesn't have to be a notation for everything.

Comment: @bof: if the OP is doing mathematical logic, then, in the object language, there does have to a notation for everything. I agree with you, if the context is ordinary mathematical writing.